# How to convert a list into xexpr?

Tags: racket

```
#lang racket
(struct result (q) #:mutable)

(define RESULT (result '()))

(define (insert-result! result val)
  (set-result-q! result (cons val (result-q result))))

(insert-result! RESULT "hello")
(insert-result! RESULT "wrold")
(print (result-q RESULT))

(define (iter l)
`(div ((class "result"))
    ,(for ([i (result-q l)])
      `(p ,i))))

(iter RESULT)
```

I'm trying to get xexpr. `RESULT` should be 
`'("wrold" "hello")` after the code run. Then in `iter` function I want to produce output:

`'(div ((class "result")) (p "world") (p "hello"))`

Somehow the code above gives me this `'(div ((class "result")) #<void>)` instead. How would I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
,@(for/list ([i (result-q l)])
    `(p ,i))
```

Notice the use of `,@` for splicing unquote, as well as `for/list` for collecting the results into a list.